# Need guidance with sending files to a .NET WCF Web Service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap, mtom

Thank you all in advance for your assistance!

I am creating a .NET WCF web service (C#) for sending emails.. basically a central emailer service that all internal apps can use. my hurdle has been email attachments (1 or more)... I have been looking for the best practices for sending binary data to a WCF web service. The following needs to be considered:

- all requests to this service will be internal
- attachments are optional but may contain more than 1
- for multiple attachments i need to ensure my service doesnt time out

I have read alot about converting binary to a base64 string but alot of the drawbacks with performance (especially with multiple files) scared me from accepting this approach. So i kept searching and found some MTOM topics which are supposed to be more efficient for binary file transfers.

Basically i need guidance on what approach is the best practice for this type of functionality and ideally some sample code to send me on my way.

Thanks again in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

quashBox,

I just went through this exercise just last week, the key is to stream the MTOM attachments, this seems to be the most efficient way of sending larger attachments. Here are a few resources that I just dug up and found to be extremely helpful...

MSDN - How to Enable Streaming
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

Transfer large messages in WCF blog
http://nagavitalp.blogspot.com/2011/04/transfer-large-messages-in-wcf-part-1.html

WCF Streaming: Upload files over HTTP
http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html

A few high-level keys:

your message contracts need to have a single Stream body member, all other elements need to be placed in the message header, like (sorry for the VB.NET, but the shop I'm currently in uses it):

```
<MessageContract()>
Public Class StreamAttachmentRequest

<MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)>
Public Property AttachmentName As String

<MessageBodyMember(Order:=1)>
Public Property Attachment As Stream

End Class
```

your binding has to be configured for streaming MTOM. like...

```
   <bindings>

    <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="TestCaseBasicBinding"

    messageEncoding="Mtom"

    transferMode="StreamedRequest"

    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

    closeTimeout="00:30:00"

    openTimeout="00:30:00"

    receiveTimeout="00:30:00"

    sendTimeout="00:30:00">
```

you may have to set the max request length if you're transferring really large attachments

```
 <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
```

Good luck with it,
Patrick

Comment: so if i use this approach all other parameters for my service; such as recipients, subject, etc... have to be moved to the header ? Also then what happens if we have multiple attachments ?